# Why pass by reference doesn't seem to work in this code and obj1.value is still a outside of a function

Tags: javascript

pass by reference is not working here when we assign obj2 to obj1 in a function it doesn't work outside the function and obj1 is retaining its original value but why?

```js
let obj1 = {
  value: 'a'
}

let obj2 = {
  value: 'b'
}

obj3 = obj2;

function change(obj1, obj2) {
  obj1 = obj2
  obj2.value = 'c'
}


change(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1.value)
```

Comment: `function change() { ... }` without parameters should work

Comment: also what is the purpose of `obj3`?

Comment: here is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/5924640

Comment: In JavaScript everything is passed by a value. When an object is "passed by reference", actually a copy of the reference is passed, that copy is a value. This is called "_pass by sharing_".

Comment: @Teemu aka 'call by sharing': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `obj1` inside the function will refer be a **local variable** which is referring to global variable `obj1`. But when you reassign `obj1` the reference is removed so that's why the `value` is not changed and then it has no connection with the `obj1` of global scope.

I just changed the names of variable to show what is going on.

```js
let obj1gl = {
  value:'a'
}

let obj2gl = {
  value:'b'
}


function change(obj1,obj2){
  console.log(obj1gl === obj1); //true
  //this line removes the reference.
  obj1 = obj2
  console.log(obj1gl === obj1); //false
  obj2.value = 'c'
}


change(obj1gl,obj2gl);
```

Comment: "that's why the value is not changed and then it has no connection with the obj1 of global scope." but OP's snippet doesn't seem to attempt to change obj1. It'd be more interesting the snippet was edited to: obj1.value = 'c'

Comment: @AnonEq OP is clearly saying _"obj1 is retaining its original value but why?"_. It means he expects a change in `obj1`.

Comment: OP's question's language indicates they 'expects' a change in obj1. Whether their code aligns with the 'conditions for obj1 change' they seek to clarify is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

It is a concept of local vs global scoping.

though variable names are identical but when you have passed in a function, their scope is limited to that function and so it does not affect global variables having similar names.

console.log is outside of that function which picks up unaffected global variable.

One solution could be to use global variables inside function and do not pass anything in the function else use different naming convention amongst local and global variables, then modifying global variable will work inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

JS primitives are passed by value.

JS objects are also passed by value, but the value is a copy of a reference.

```js
//global object in this runtime env is 'window'
var obj1 = { //global scope obj1
  value: 'a'
}

var obj2 = { //global scope obj2
  value: 'b'
}


function change(obj1, obj2) { //js = "pass by copy of reference"
  obj1 = obj2              //obj1's value is now a reference (aka an address in memory) to global obj2
  console.log(typeof obj1) //logs 'object', (meaning local var obj1's value is a reference )
  obj1.value = 'c'         //global obj2 value changed.
  console.log(window.obj2) //logs 'value': 'c'
  console.log(window.obj1) //logs 'value': 'a'
}


change(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1.value) //logs 'a'
console.log(obj2.value) //logs 'c'
```